# Formatting with the map() function in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting

I'm writing code to convert mach to feet/second and I want to use the map function with the lambda operator to convert it. I have a parameter that's a list called machList. I'm able to convert successfully, but I'm having trouble formatting it correctly so the answer doesn't come out as the whole list of converted answers.

My code so far looks like this:

```
def machToFPS(machList):
    for x in machList:   
        FPS = map(lambda x: x*1116.4370079,machList)        
        print('{0}'.format(x), "mach(s) is equivalent to",FPS, "feet per second.")
```

The output I get if machList = [1,5,3] is:

```
1 mach(s) is equivalent to [1116.4370079, 5582.1850395, 3349.3110237] feet per second.

5 mach(s) is equivalent to [1116.4370079, 5582.1850395, 3349.3110237] feet per second.

3 mach(s) is equivalent to [1116.4370079, 5582.1850395, 3349.3110237] feet per second.

I want my answer to look like this:

1 mach is equivalent    to      1116.4370079        feet    per second.

5       mach    is  equivalent  to      5582.1850395        feet    per second.

3       mach    is  equivalent  to      3349.3110237        feet    per second.
```

Could someone please help me? The map() function is throwing me off.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you `need` to use **`map`** function, then:

```
machList = [1,5,3]

def machToFPS(machList):
    FPS = map(lambda x: x*1116.4370079,machList) 
    for i,x in enumerate(FPS):
        print('{} mach(s) is equivalent to {} feet per second.'.format(machList[i], x))

machToFPS(machList)
```

If not, just do it as it's shown in the next answer (only with a for loop).

**Output:**

```
1 mach(s) is equivalent to 1116.4370079 feet per second.
5 mach(s) is equivalent to 5582.1850395 feet per second.
3 mach(s) is equivalent to 3349.3110237 feet per second.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `map` function. In fact, using it is what's causing this issue.

When you iterate over `machList`, `x` is equal to an individual item in the `machList` list.

So `x` is an integer 1, 3, or 5.

So all you would have to do is this:

```
def machToFPS(machList):
  for x in machList
    FPS = x * 1116.4370079
    print('{0}'.format(x), "mach(s) is equivalent to",FPS, "feet per second.")
```

And that should output your desired text.

In order to use the map function to get the same output, you can do this:

```
def machToFPS(machList):
  fpsList = map(lambda x: x*1116.4370079,machList)
  for x in fpsList
    print('{0}'.format(x), "mach(s) is equivalent to",FPS, "feet per second.")
```

Comment: I understand how to do it without the map function but the whole point of writing this code is to use it. Is there a way you'd recommend using it for this?

Comment: I'll update my answer to include code that does it with the map function, if that's what's required of you.

Answer (score 0):

`map(function, arg_list)` returns a list containing the results of calling `function` with each element of the array `arg_list`. You will need to iterate the results of the map call.

One way to do this is to have your lambda function return a tuple instead:

```
def mach_to_fps(mach_list):
    # Returning a tuple from the lambda allows the print to get all of its information
    # from the contents of the return list alone.
    for mach_fps_tuple in map(lambda mach: (mach, mach * 1116.4370079), mach_list):
        # *mach_fps_tuple breaks the tuple out into separate arguments for format.
        # Using old-style format would look like this:
        #    'mach(%s) is equivalent to %s feet per second' % mach_fps_tuple
        print('mach({0}) is equivalent to {1} feet per second'.format(*mach_fps_tuple))

mach_to_fps([1, 5, 3])

$ python mach.py
mach(1) is equivalent to 1116.4370079 feet per second
mach(5) is equivalent to 5582.1850395 feet per second
mach(3) is equivalent to 3349.3110237 feet per second
```

Note that I formatted this using PEP8, which is highly recommended.

Comment: I haven't learned about PEP8 but I appreciate you taking the time to explain it. It was definitely a good teaching lesson!

Comment: Glad to help! I make sure all of my developers are comfortable with PEP8, as a common look to code formatting helps everyone read it more easily. There are plugins for many code editors that will flag non-compliant lines. I use flake8 in emacs. Sublime Text also has a PEP8 formatter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> machList = [1,5,3]
>>> fmt='{} is equivalent to {} feet per second'
>>> map(lambda x: fmt.format(x, x*1116.4370079), machList)
['1 is equivalent to 1116.4370079 feet per second', '5 is equivalent to 5582.1850395 feet per second', '3 is equivalent to 3349.3110237 feet per second']
```

Then to print it:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(map(lambda x: fmt.format(x, x*1116.4370079), machList))
1 is equivalent to 1116.4370079 feet per second
5 is equivalent to 5582.1850395 feet per second
3 is equivalent to 3349.3110237 feet per second
```

But I think a list comprehension is easier to comprehend here (and probably faster) since there is no need for a lambda:

```
>>> print '\n'.join([fmt.format(x, x*1116.4370079) for x in machList])
1 is equivalent to 1116.4370079 feet per second
5 is equivalent to 5582.1850395 feet per second
3 is equivalent to 3349.3110237 feet per second
```